# Reassignment of a variable referencing an array reassigns the original variable

Tags: php

I have this code:

```php
$originalBar = [
  'baz' => 18
];

function modify (&$bar) {
  $bar['test'] = true;
  $bar = [
    'data' => 42
  ];

  global $originalBar;
  echo 'same ' . ($bar === $originalBar) . PHP_EOL;
}

modify($originalBar);
var_dump($originalBar);
```

I know that since the function accepts an argument by reference, any passed array will be modified. So I expect to change the original array with:

```
$bar['test'] = true;
```

...and set key `test` of `$originalBar` to `true`. However, when I reassign `$bar` I expect that the variable no longer points to the original array (`$originalBar`) and any changes onwards don't modify it. Obviously, that's not the case because the output is:

```
same 1
array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
  int(42)
}
```

By reassigning `$bar`, I reassigned `$originalBar` too. I expected that this would function the same way as it does in JavaScript, which is why I was confused at first.

My question is - is this documented somewhere? I read the [Passing by Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) documentation but I didn't find that there.

**Edit:** If instead of doing this in the *modify* function:

```php
$bar = [
  'data' => 42
];
```

...I do this:

```php
$arr = [
  'data' => 42
];

$bar = &$arr;
```

...I get my initially expected result:

```
same 
array(2) {
  ["baz"]=>
  int(18)
  ["test"]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

It's interesting that in this case, `$originalBar` is not assigned to the value of `$arr` and keeps its old value instead.

Comment: Ummm... What?  You reassigned `$bar = [
    'data' => 42
  ];` and as that's a reference to `$originalBar` it modified that.  What don't you understand?

Comment: Why would it be documented? It's the expected behavior... You're making a reference to the original var from `$bar`. Essentially `$bar` becomes synonymous with whatever you pass to it.

Comment: Also, *I expected that this would function the same way as it does in JavaScript*?!

Comment: Objects are passed by reference in JS by default, but if you reassign the argument inside the function, the original variable is left intact. I think I've had the wrong impression because the PHP docs say "You can pass a variable by reference to a function so the function can modify the _variable_." So passing by reference is done so you can modify the original _variable_, not just the object it _points to_.

Comment: I think this question is legitimate, but the example is a bit misleading. The question seems to be (if I'm understanding correctly): why is it that in PHP, calling `function($arr) { $arr['foo'] = 1; }` on an array doesn't reflect changes to the array in the calling scope without `&`? In JS, the original memory location would be modified, while PHP would make use of copy on write inside the function.

Comment: I know that JS and PHP behave differently and that PHP copies arrays. However, I expected that by adding `&` in the argument, it would behave the same way as it does in JS, but it doesn't.

Comment: It's confusing, because the reference operator is really doing two things: 1) exposing the original memory location for reassignment and 2) allowing a complex structure such as an array to be mutated. In JS, the first is never possible and the second is always possible. PHP gives some "flexibility" in these regards where on the one hand, `function ($var)` is much more restrictive than most langs while `function (&$var)` is more permissive than most languages, which is not exactly intuitive.

Comment: ^ that. This is what sparked my confusion.

Comment: @ggorlen I don't think that's an accurate description. PHP references do one, very specific, thing: they make two names aliases for the same variable. There is no special case allowing the array to be mutated - that's just the variable behaving normally; and there's no memory location being "exposed", that makes it sound too much like a C pointer, which it definitely is not.

Comment: @IMSoP Of course, it's not a C pointer (apples and oranges), but the ability to do `$foo = 15;` inside a pass-by-reference function and have that be reflected in the original memory location is unusual and surprising behavior for almost any non-pointer language (Perl may be an exception? I'm not sure). Additionally, the copy-on-write behavior is also unusual for a high-level language. Passing by reference modifies the default for both of these behaviors, and I think OP wasn't entirely grasping that neither pass-by-reference OR pass-by-value works quite like JS.

Comment: @ggorlen Not really, that's literally what "pass by reference" means in any language which has that feature; it's rarely described in terms of "memory locations", but "changes are reflected in the original variable" is pretty much the definition of "passed by ref". C is really the odd one out in using pointer types directly to handle that scenario. Copy-on-write is just an implementation detail; unless you're looking at memory usage, you can imagine an array passed by value as being copied as soon as the function is called. The only difference with JS is that in PHP an array is not an object.

Comment: Check the edit to my question. I think it's even more confusing that doing `$bar = &$newValue` does **not** modify `$originalBar` but `$bar = $newValue` does. If "they make two names aliases for the same variable" as @IMSoP said, shouldn't it change the value of `$originalBar` in both scenarios?

Comment: @HristiyanDodov I prefer to spell `$bar = &$newValue` as `$bar =& $newValue`, because the action isn't really "assign something to `$bar`" but "bind the name `$bar` as an alias to `$newValue`". In binding that alias, it discards any previous binding for that name. This part is unusual in PHP, but the original question is plain "pass by reference" as implemented in many languages.

Comment: @IMSoP Good point about pass-by-reference, but the idea I'm trying to convey is that: 1) JS doesn't have pass-by-reference (most high level languages don't) and 2) PHP's pass-by-value works differently than most high level languages due to COW. I'm curious if you can take a look at and critique my answer below.

Comment: @ggorlen There are certainly plenty of languages that don't support pass-by-reference, but it's hardly unusual; C# has it, and that's about as high-level as any mainstream language you'll find. And I really don't know what COW has to do with anything here; it's just an optimisation, and in terms of *behaviour* is entirely equivalent to a naive pass-by-value which creates a copy of the variable when the function is called.

Comment: @IMSoP Good point on C#, but I'm not sure I follow on the "naive pass-by-value which creates a copy of the variable". In JS, it's pass-by-value, but I can set properties on the object and no copy occurs at any point. But that's not the case in PHP--regardless of when it happens, it *does* happen, and variables are copied on write. I get that COW is just an optimization, but regardless of mechanism, the key is that it's copied, which is surprising. In no way am I suggesting that COW (versus immediate copying) matters, just that the copy does happen (although, arguably, COW makes it less clear).

Comment: @ggorlen Yes, objects - in both languages - are passed with special semantics, so leave those aside for a second. First, consider a string, with normal pass-by-value logic; when you call `a="hello"; foo(a);`, a copy of the string is created in memory, for use inside the function `foo`. That's exactly the same in both languages. Now, passing an object is a bit tricksy, because what gets passed is a special pointer to the mutable object; so the *pointer* is copied, but not the *object*; again, this is the same in both JS and PHP (and pretty much all other OO languages).

Comment: Yup--I'm clear on all that. I think a fundamental difference I've ignored up until now is that PHP arrays !== JS arrays which I think accounts for some of the confusion in this thread. Passing an object or array into a function in JS both have similar behavior, while in PHP, passing an object by value allows mutation to the original (much as you'd expect in JS), while passing an array by value causes a copy.

Comment: @ggorlen Yep, that's it. Both languages have two categories: "things that are objects" and "things that are not objects"; the way each category is passed is the same, but the categories have different members. In JS, arrays are in the "things that are objects" category; in PHP, they are in the "things that are not objects" category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to correct some misapprehensions in the question, comments, and self-answer.

- Passing *objects* in PHP behave similarly to passing *objects* in JS. This is *not* passing by reference, but passing an "object pointer" by value; the difference is subtle but important. When you pass a variable into a function by reference, you can assign *any value* to that variable inside the function, and it will have that value on the outside of the function as well. Passing an object *does not give you this ability* - you can't replace it with a different object, or with the value `42` - but it does let you *mutate* the object - you can call a method or set a property, and the code outside the function will be able to see the result.
- The difference between JS and PHP here is that arrays in JS are objects, but in PHP they are not, so they do not have this "mutable object pointer" behaviour when passed by value.
- Pass by reference, as implemented in PHP and many other languages, means that *any* assignment or modification of the variable inside the function is reflected outside the function. There is nothing special about arrays here, the same thing happens with `$foo=42;` or `$foo++;`.
- JS does not have an equivalent for explicit pass-by-reference, but other languages such as C# and Pascal have the same concept with different syntaxes.

Things get more unusual in PHP when you assign by reference (`$foo =& $bar`); one way to think of it is that you have one variable, and you're giving it two names.

I prefer to spell what you wrote as `$bar = &$newValue` as `$bar =& $newValue`, because the action isn't really "assign something to `$bar`" but "bind the name `$bar` as an alias for something". In binding that alias, it discards any previous binding for that name, so it undoes the "pass by reference" nature of the name.

Comment: The clarification about `=&` was really important for me. In [the PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), they write it as `$var = &$othervar;` and also call it "assignment by reference". Pretty confusing.

Answer (score 2):

A possible point of confusion is that arrays in PHP are not the same as arrays/objects in JS and instead behave like strings or numbers for pass-by-value purposes.

In PHP, arrays passed by value will be [copied on write](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/zvals/memory_management.html) when dirtied in a function, much like strings or numerical types:

```
function modify($a) {
    global $foo;
    var_dump($a === $foo); # => true

    $a['hello'] = "world";
    var_dump($a === $foo); # => false, we wrote to $a and it was copied.
}

$foo = ["baz" => 42];    
modify($foo);
var_dump($foo); # => ["baz" => 42] (the original was unchanged after the function call)
```

From a JS perspective, we might expect that `$a['hello'] = "world";` would reflect on the outer object and not cause a copy to be created:

```js
const modify = a => {
  console.log(a === foo); // => true
  a.hello = "world";
  console.log(a === foo); // => true
};

const foo = {bar: "baz"};
modify(foo);
console.log(foo); // => {"bar": "baz", "hello": "world"}
```

The pass-by-value behavior in PHP is unsurprising on objects:

```
class A {
    function __construct() {
        $this->bar = "hello";
    }
}

function modify($a) {
    global $foo;
    var_dump($a === $foo); # => true

    $a->bar = "world";
    var_dump($a === $foo); # => true
}

$foo = new A();
modify($foo);
var_dump($foo); /* => object(A)#1 (1) {
                        ["bar"]=>
                        string(5) "world"
                      } 
                */
```

---

In PHP, passing by reference enables mutation of the original array:

```
function modify(&$a) {
    global $foo;
    var_dump($a === $foo); # => true

    $a['hello'] = "world";
    var_dump($a === $foo); # => true
}

$foo = ["baz" => 42];    
modify($foo);
print_r($foo); # => ["baz" => 42, "hello" => "world"]
```

A reference variable can also be reassigned to a new value:

```
function modify(&$a) {
    global $foo;
    var_dump($a === $foo); # => true

    $a = "world";
    var_dump($a === $foo); # => true
}

$foo = ["baz" => 42];    
modify($foo);
print_r($foo); # => "world"
```

Since JS does't support passing by reference, there is no clear parallel between JS and PHP for these behaviors, aside from the usage of the reference operator to support JS/object-like mutations of arrays inside a function.

Comment: First, the array behaviour is only surprising if you expect arrays to be objects; they are in JS, they are not in PHP. Set `$foo = "hello"` and `$a = "world"` in your first example, and the behaviour becomes exactly as expected. This has nothing to do with copy-on-write, which is just an internal optimisation. Secondly, as I mentioned in comments under the question, the pass-by-reference behaviour is *exactly what pass-by-reference does in every language that supports it*.

Comment: On example 1), I don't see how `$foo = "hello"` changes the behavior, and it does seem to have to do with COW, because in JS the original reference is updated rather than copied upon mutation. I agree on the pass-by-reference behavior being the same as any other language--I'll try to clarify that point that it's "surprising" only in relation to JS. PHP's behavior for pass-by-ref and pass-by-value are both different than as you'd expect from JS.

Comment: Again, in JS, the array is mutated *because arrays are implemented as objects*; that's it, that's the only difference. Consider these three examples: string, same as JS https://3v4l.org/DRlXe; object, same as JS https://3v4l.org/p9Deo; array, works like a string in PHP but would be like an object in JS https://3v4l.org/hOM1V Copy-on-write is just a fancy way of implementing "copy when you pass to the function", *which is exactly what happens with a string in both languages*.

Comment: Yep, I see your point. Updated my answer to better reflect all this (I hope). Thanks for your patience and explanations. Having said that, in Python, Java, Ruby, (possibly others?) arrays are also mutable when passed by value, so am I correct in thinking that PHP is the outlier in treating arrays as "primitive" in this regard?

Comment: Yeah, I think array-as-object is pretty common in languages which were designed as OO form the beginning. PHP had OO added later, so already had array-as-primitive, and it didn't make sense to change it; there are probably other languages in the same situation. There are also really pure OO languages like Smalltalk where *nothing* is a primitive.

Answer (score 0):

That's not documented anywhere because it's the expected behavior. I have just misread. The PHP docs say:

> You can pass a variable by reference to a function so the function can modify the **variable**.

I've had the wrong impression because objects are passed by reference by default in JavaScript and there, reassigning the argument variable doesn't change the original variable.

The intention of passing by reference in PHP is to be able to modify the **variable**, not just the object it points to. Meaning, you can not only change the object, but also reassign the passed variable.

As @ggorlen said in the comments to my question:

> The reference operator is really doing two things: 1) exposing the original memory location for reassignment and 2) allowing a complex structure such as an array to be mutated. In JS, the first is never possible and the second is always possible. PHP gives some "flexibility" in these regards where on the one hand, `function ($var)` is much more restrictive than most langs while `function (&$var)` is more permissive than most languages, which is not exactly intuitive.

Comment: It also states.... Note: There is no reference sign on a function call - only on function definitions. Function definitions alone are enough to correctly pass the argument by reference. As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use & in foo(&$a);. And as of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was removed, so using it will raise a fatal error.

Comment: Try to avoid statements like "objects are passed by reference", for exactly this reason: there is a big difference between passing around a mutable pointer, and passing a reference to a variable.